# Unable to deploy OpenTelemetryCollector on Private GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, open-telemetry, gke-networking

I am unable to deploy OpenTelemetryCollector in private GKE cluster getting below error

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "otel.yaml":
  Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "mopentelemetrycollector.kb.io": 
  failed to call webhook:
  Post "https://opentelemetry-operator-webhook-service.opentelemetry-operator-system.svc:443/mutate-opentelemetry-io-v1alpha1-opentelemetrycollector?timeout=10s": 
  context deadline exceeded
```

I have deployed cert-manget and Opentelemetry Operator as well

```
kubectl get po -n cert-manager
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cert-manager-6f65f67cf-s5jpl              1/1     Running   0          75m
cert-manager-cainjector-d76d58bf9-w4nsr   1/1     Running   0          75m
cert-manager-webhook-5f8fcdb859-6rlz4     1/1     Running   0          75m
```

```
kubectl get po -n opentelemetry-operator-system
NAME                                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
opentelemetry-operator-controller-manager-98588ddcf-fx7sp   2/2     Running   0          70m
```

Cert-manger images used:

- `quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-cainjector:v1.11.0`
- `quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-webhook:v1.11.0`
- `quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-controller:v1.11.0`

Inside the cert-manager-webhook pod getting below logs

`http: TLS handshake error from x.x.x.x:34552: EOF`

I have followed the below link
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/issues/100
but it didn't helped me.

I am expecting a solution to deploy opentelemetry collector in my GKE cluster

Comment: I would use helm, not operator - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/issues/625

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and discovered the issue.

GKE has a default firewall that allows the control plane API server to only talk to nodes over ports 10250 and 443.  The opentelemetry webhook uses port 9443.

I added a new firewall rule to my cluster (this is a sample... modify as appropriate for your cluster)

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create gke-opentelemetry-webhook \ 
--action ALLOW \ 
--direction INGRESS \ 
--source-ranges 172.16.0.16/28 \ 
--rules tcp:9443 \ 
--target-tags gke-cluster-19216119-node
```

At that point I was able to create the collector.

If you look at the description of the opentelemetry operator pod, you will see:

Args:
`--webhook-port=9443`